# Glassfish 2.1 won't start after changing Maximum Pool Size

Tags: web-server, glassfish

I'm running **Glassfish 2.1** on an Ubuntu server, I was trying to test something, so I change in the administrative console on localhost:4848 the Maximum Pool Size to 1, I stopped the server, but when I tried to start it again (from the command line)

```
 sudo /opt/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
```

It got stuck in

> [#|2013-04-24T11:20:32.741-0500|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MQJMSRA_RA1101:
>   SJSMQ JMS Resource Adapter starting...|#]

And just hanged there.
I thought that maybe It was my configuration change that is causing this problem, but I couldn't find where is the configuration file, I searched under domains/domain1/config with no luck, I also google it, but couldn't find useful info.

So, Its possible that my configuration change is the one affecting glassfish?
In that case, where can I change back that configuration?
Or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, It was.

The configuration file is **domain.xml**
And is under: **glassfishHome/domains/domain1/config/**

I change the value of max-thread-pool-size from 1 to 5 and I started the server and everything worked fine.

```
 <thread-pool idle-thread-timeout-in-seconds="120"
 max-thread-pool-size="5" min-thread-pool-size="0" num-work-queues="1"
 thread-pool-id="thread-pool-1"/>
```